# How do I create new instances of a Vue component, and subsuqently destroy them, with methods?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to add components to the DOM dynamically on user input. I effectively have a situation with ±200 buttons/triggers which, when clicked, need to create/show an instance of `childComponent` (which is a sort of infowindow/modal).

I would also then need to be able to remove/hide them later when the user 'closes' the component.

I'm imagining something like this?

```
<template>
  <div ref="container">
    <button @click="createComponent(1)" />
    ...
    <button @click="createComponent(n)" />


    <childComponent ref="cc53" :num="53" v-on:kill="destroyComponent" />
    ...
    <childComponent ref="ccn" :num="n" v-on:kill="destroyComponent"/>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
import childComponent from '@/components/ChildComponent'
export default {
  components: {childComponent},
  methods: {
    createComponent (num) {
      // How do I create an instance of childComponent with prop 'num' and add it to this.$refs.container?
    },
    destroyComponent (vRef) {
      // How do I destroy an instance of childComponent?
      this.vRef.$destroy();
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

The number of possible `childComponent` instances required is finite, immutable and known before render, so I could loop and `v-show` them, but your typical user will probably only need to look at a few, and certainly only a few simultaneously.

**My questions:**

Firstly, given there are ±200 of them, is there any performance benefit to only creating instances dynamically as and when required, vs. `v-for` looping `childComponents` and let Vue manage the DOM?

Secondly, even if `v-for` is the way to go for this particular case, how would one handle this if the total number of possible childComponents is not known or dynamic? Is this a job for [Render Functions and JSX](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand, you want to display a list of the same component that take `:num` as a prop.

First, you have to keep in mind that Vue is a "Data driven application", wich means that you need to represent your list as Data in an `array` or an `object`, in your case you can use a `myList` array and `v-for` loop to display your child components list in the template.

The add and remove operations must be donne on the `myList` array it self, once done, it will be automatically applied on your template.

- To **add** a new instance just use `myList.push(n)`
- To **remove** an instance use `myLsit.splice(myLsit.indexOf(n), 1);`

The result should look like this :

```
<template>

    <input v-model="inputId" />
    <button @click="addItem(inputId)">Add Item</button>

    <childComponent
        v-for="itemId in myList" 
        :key="itemId" 
        :ref="'cc' + itemId" 
        :num="itemId"
        @kill="removeItem(itemId)"
   />

</template>

<script>
    data(){
        return{
            inputId : 0,
            myList : []
        }
    },
    methods:{
        addItem(id){
            this.myList.push(id)
        },
        removeItem(id){
            this.myLsit.splice(this.myLsit.indexOf(id), 1)
        }
    }

</script>
```

Ps :

- Didn't test the code, if there is any error just tell me
- `@kill` method must be emitted by the `childComponent`, `$emit('kill', this.num)`
- [Here is an excellent tutorial to better understand `v-for`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Hcswbo0nCY)

Answer (score 0):

**Performance Penalties**

As there is only a limited possibility of ±200 elements, I highly doubt that it can cause any performance issue, and for further fine-tuning, instead of using `v-show`, you can use `v-if` it'll reduce the total memory footprint, but increases the render time if you're going to change the items constantly.

**Other Approaches**

If there weren't limited possibilities of `x` elements, it'd be still and `v-for` having items which contain the `v-if` directive.

But if the user could only see one item (or multiple but limited items) at the same time, instead of `v-for`, It'd much better to directly bind the properties to the `childComponent`.

For example, if the child component is a modal that'll be shown by the application when a user clicked on the edit button for a row of a table. Instead of having `x` number of modals, each having editable contents of a row and showing the modal related to the edit button, we can have one modal and bind form properties to it. This approach usually implemented by having a state management library like `vuex`.

Finally, This is an implementation based on `vuex`, that can be used, if the user could only see one `childComponent` at the same time, it can be easily extended to support multiple `childComponent` viewed at the same time.

**store.js**

```
export Store {
    state: {
        childComponentVisible: false,
        childComponentNumber: 0
    },
    mutations: {
        setChildComponentNumber(state, value) {
            if(typeof value !== 'number')
                return false;

            state.childComponentNumber = value;
        },
        setChildComponentVisibility(state, value) {
            if(typeof value !== 'boolean')
                return false;

            state.childComponentVisible = value;
        }
    }
}
```

**child-component.vue**

```
<template>
    <p>
        {{ componentNumber }}
        <span @click="close()">Close</span>
    </p>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        methods: {
            close() {
                this.$store.commit('setChildComponentVisibility', false);
            }
        }
        computed: {
            componentNumber() {
                return this.$store.state.childComponentNumber;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**list-component.vue**

```
<template>
    <div class="list-component">
        <button v-for="n in [1,2,3,4,5]" @click="triggerChildComponent(n)">
            {{ n }}
        </button>
        <childComponent v-if="childComponentVisible"/>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        methods: {
            triggerChildComponent(n) {
                this.$store.commit('setChildComponentNumber', n);
                this.$store.commit('setChildComponentVisibility', true);
            }
        },
        computed: {
            childComponentVisible() {
                return this.$store.state.childComponentVisible;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**Note**: The code written above is abstract only and isn't tested, you might need to change it a little bit to make it work for your own situation.

For more information on `vuex` check out its documentation [here](https://vuex.vuejs.org/).